# Does Open edX or Moodle meets my criteria?

Tags: moodle, openedx

I am comparing these two systems (Open edX and Moodle) if they meet my specific criteria.

I need to be able to override the functionality of the specific course in the way that I can have two courses with slightly different functionality. Following features should be mandatory for one course and should be disabled for another.

- Allow course use for anonymous users
- Certification is not required
- Ability to use course in the random order
- No requirement of the minimum hours
- Use of notebook is optional

Another course should have a complete opposite of this features.

- Course use for logged in users
- Certification is required
- Use of course in the strict order only
- Minimum hours requirement
- Use of notebook is mandatory

Do these features require coding or can be configured?

Answer (score 2):

> Do these features require coding or can be configured?

I can only speak for Moodle:

- **Allow course use for anonymous users:** Possible without coding (in Moodle this is roughly called "to allow guests users to access an specific course").
- **Certification is not required:** possible without coding (default behaviour).
- **Ability to use course in the random order:** possible without coding  (default behaviour).
- **No requirement of the minimum hours:** possible without coding  (default behaviour).
- **Use of notebook is optional:** I'm not sure what do you mean by "notebook", if you mean a "blog" or a "forum", it is possible to allow its use optionally. If you mean something else, like an integration with Microsoft OneNote, that may be possible with plugins (but you should check if they exist). AFAIK There is no "notebook" in Moodle without plugins.

About the opposite needs you mentioned:

- **Course use for logged in users:** Possible without coding (default behaviour).
- **Certification is required:** If by "certification required" you mean that certification is a requirement to start a course this is definitely NOT possible without coding. The only Moodle solution that grants and tracks certification statuses over time is the official enterprise Moodle version (Moodle for Workplace: https://moodle.com/workplace/)
- **Use of course in the strict order only:** NOT possible without coding. Again, the only Moodle solution that restricts courses access based in other course completion statuses is Moodle for Workplace.
- **Minimum hours requirement**: AFAIK there is no standard time tracking solution that grants course completion based in the time expended within the course, so coding would be needed. There exist plugins that calculate times expended within courses or the platform.
- **Use of notebook is mandatory:** Unless you download a "notebook" plugin that can be instanced as a course activity, I don't think you will be able to make its use mandatory.